# A word for an opinion phrased as a question

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a name for a request or opinion re-phrased into a question? Sentences like:

"Would it be a good idea to start cleaning up now?"

"Do you think we should complete this project in time?"

"Do you think we should follow basic hygenic standards in this team?"

Note: This question is similar to [Suggestion phrased as a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54154/suggestion-phrased-as-a-question) , but not identical in my opinion, since the formulations in this question are (subjectively) more covert.

Comment: There is nothing in any of those sentences that implies an opinion on the part of the person asking the question.

Comment: @Jason Bassford : Precisely. That's why it's becoming a popular way of urging people on. Plausible deniability.

Comment: In terms of pragmatics, they're [a subset of: interrogative-form] hedged suggestions. The hedge grows thinner with their negative counterparts: "Don't you think we should follow basic hygenic standards in this team?" Hedged requests often drop the question mark nowadays: "Can/Could you [just] close the window[?]"; adding 'please' probably makes one again blameable if things go wrong ("Could you just close the window, please[?]")

Comment: Thank you Edwin. "Suggestive question" is another term I found.

Comment: I've heard of a *counterfeit question* that pretends to seek information but really makes a statement, dishonestly, through a strong hint.

Answer (score 3):

It's called a *leading question* although to the extent that some answers can be considered obvious, these are also partially *rhetorical questions*

Comment: Not all leading questions are geared to persuade a person to perform a certain physical action (or indeed to get an opinion across), though they are intended to provoke a desired response of _some_ type. Have you any substantiating references?

Answer (score -1):

There might be several ways to categorize these questions.

### Leading question

> A *leading question* is a question which subtly prompts the respondent to answer in a particular way. Leading questions are generally undesirable as they result in false or slanted information.
>   [source](https://www.mediacollege.com/journalism/interviews/leading-questions.html)

### Request

You might find this question and [answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/332170/3306) enlightening:

> This is not a rhetorical question; it is a *request*.

### Pointed question

> [a pointed question/look/remark]: a direct question, look etc that deliberately shows that you are annoyed, bored, or disapprove of something
>   [source](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/a-pointed-question-look-remark)

One could categorize the OP's example statements in this fashion:

"Would it be a good idea to start cleaning up now?" = Request

"Do you think we should complete this project in time?" = Leading question

"Do you think we should follow basic hygienic standards in this team?" = Pointed question