# Could you get me a glass of water, please? Is this an interrogative sentence or an imperative sentence.?

Tags: sentence, imperatives

Could you get me a glass of water, please? Is this an interrogative sentence or an imperative sentence?

Comment: It could be either. It depends on how you want to interpret it. Going strictly by the grammar (because of the *could*), it would be interrogative. But going by the intended meaning, it could be seen as imperative (a nicely worded order). Are you looking at syntax or semantics?

Comment: Syntactically, it is an interrogative sentence: it matches the form. Pragmatically, this is a conventional request; it has a conventional form, includes _please_, and is intended as an impositive. It could be considered an order if it were delivered in the appropriate manner (which can't be represented in print), but the cover term is "impositive", because the intent is to impose the speaker's will on the addressee. It's not an imperative, because _imperative_ refers only to the **form** of the utterance, and this has the form of an _interrogative_.

Comment: Use a period instead of a question mark for a firm request. A question mark corresponds to a desired verbal answer except in rhetorical questions (zero response).

Comment: Polite requests stated as questions should be ended with a period.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Suggestion phrased as a question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/54154/suggestion-phrased-as-a-question)

Comment: It's a directive but not an imperative. In terms of grammatical structure, it's an interrogative, but it's not used to ask a question. I'm not asking for an answer, I'm asking for a glass of water.

Comment: @Stockfish may I disagree?

Comment: Who's asking???

Comment: @Will Crawford: By all means :) I suppose the CMS supports my viewpoint, but then I could be wrong. Have a faint recollection of having read such a thing.

Comment: Syntactically, the sentence seems interrogative, but it being a request should it be an imperative? As it has the modal 'could'  then it cannot be an imperative and moreover it ends with a question mark so I was a bit puzzled what type of sentence it is. If this is a sentence given in a question paper and asked to mention it's kind, then what should I call it?

Comment: @AmritaEnakshiMukherjee You can call it an interrogative directive. See my comment above.

Comment: @HotLicks quite! This question's more in the area of culture and interpersonal relationships, really :)

Answer (score 1):

As written, it's a request, rather than a command.

This is because it uses the *modal* verb, *could*, which is used to form polite or formal requests and invitations¹. It makes the request slightly less direct than *can* or *will*.

Whether it's one that is genuinely allowing for a negative response is completely context-dependent. If it's your boss, they probably aren't expecting you to say "no", but in any healthy working environment you should be able to demur - if you have something else you're supposed to be doing - but you may be in trouble if you don't comply. If it's a friend or a partner, one hopes that an occasional "no" is acceptable (though too many negative responses will likely spoil the relationship).

[This answer is biased because the most recent occasions when I've spoken like this, it has been a plea rather than an order. If I'm in a restaurant, I'll be surprised to be told "No" to such a request, but even so, it *is* a question. I just might not like the answer.]

---

¹ See [British Council - LearnEnglish Teens](https://learnenglishteens.britishcouncil.org/grammar/intermediate-grammar/can-could-would-invitations-offers-requests-permission), and [Learn English - Online](http://www.learnenglish-online.com/grammar/modals/requests.html).

Comment: "Please get me a glass of water" is also a directive, but this time it **is** an imperative. It's not, of course, an interrogative, though.

Comment: Yes, exactly! This sort of phrasing is often an imperative *disguised* as an interrogative, but this particular example falls (for me, at least) squarely in the "asking nicely" rather than "telling" category :) but as @HotLicks commented, "Who's asking?"