# Is "Do this, please" an imperative sentence?

Tags: grammar, clauses, politeness, imperatives

In a similar vein to [Could you get me a glass of water, please? Is this an interrogative sentence or an imperative sentence.?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/543749/could-you-get-me-a-glass-of-water-please-is-this-an-interrogative-sentence-or), as a general rule, from a purely grammatical viewpoint, is a sentence an imperative one if there is a hedge, a politeness marker?

Taken at its simplest, is the sentence "Do this, please." an imperative? If not, what is it? And if so, how does this square with the concept that *please*, if taken at literal face value in that sentence, means that the listener has the right to refuse ***if** it does not please* the listener to *do*.

Comment: "Please" isn't a conditional in "do, please", is it? Traditional grammars and dictionaries seem to describe it as an adverb.

Comment: Perhaps a better example would be "imagine if you will"

Comment: I'd call "Could you get me a glass of water, please?" and "Could you get me a glass of water, please." (showing different intonation patterns) polite requests (the first the more polite), certainly not semantic interrogatives (asking for a verbal response to a question), and probably better considered separately from imperatives ("Do it!") as they acknowledge that a refusal to comply may not be unreasonable.  The snag is that 'imperative sentence' seems to have taken on a stipulative definition at times contrasting with the 'peremptory' definition of 'imperative'. This is at best a misnomer.

Answer (score 7):

**Short answer (tl;dr)**

In terms of illocutionary force, or type of speech act, the addition of the word *please* will change the sentence from an order to a polite request (all other things being equal).

However, in terms of the syntactic type of clause, the clause will remain imperative—as opposed to declarative, interrogative or exclamative—with or without the word *please*.

---

**Full answer:**

There's a problem with the term "imperative sentence". The problem is that nobody knows *exactly* what that would mean - although we might have a vague idea.

We need to differentiate between two different things: speech acts on the one hand, and grammatical types of clause on the other.

Speech acts could be, for example, statements, directives or requests for information and so forth. There are many, many different types of speech act. In contrast there are only five  basic grammatical types of main clause in English

1. Declarative clauses
2. Open interrogative clauses
3. Closed interrogative clauses
4. Exclamative clauses
5. Imperative clauses

Declarative main clauses can be subjunctive as in *God save the King!*, where the meaning is something like *May God save the King* and not *Save the King, God!*. However, outside of this very rare construction, each of the four major clause types in (1—4) above requires a finite verb.  In other words the first verb in the clause must have tense (or must be a modal verb if you believe that modal verbs don't have tense).

Imperative clauses on the other hand use a plain form of the verb (the form that you find in a bare infinitive, or after the word *to* in a *to*-infinitive). They are characterised by most often appearing without an overtly expressed subject:

6. Speak French!
7. Be quiet!

They can optionally take either an expressed second person subject, or a third person one, typically a word like *somebody* or *nobody*:

8. You shut up!
9. Everybody dance!

Imperative clauses ***always*** require the dummy auxiliary verb *do* when negated and also when emphatic stress is used:

10. Speak French!
11. Don't speak French!
12. *Do* speak French!

Consider also:

13. Be quiet!
14. Don't be quiet!
15. *Do* be quiet!

This separates imperatives from declarative or interrogative main clauses. These only use *do* if there is no auxiliary verb. No *do* is required for example, when the clause uses the  auxiliary verb *be*, unlike in the declaratives (13—15) above:

16. They are speaking French.
17. They are not speaking French.
18. They ***are*** speaking French.
19. *They do not be speaking French. (ungrammatical)
20. *They ***do*** be speaking French. (ungrammatical)

Lastly, in imperative main clauses the contracted auxiliary *don't* usually appears before the subject, not after it:

20. Don't you forget to brush your teeth!
21. Don't anybody move!

**The Original Poster's example**:

> 21. Do this, please.

The OP asks whether adding *please* to an imperative sentence changes the type of sentence. The answer depends on whether the Original Poster is asking about the types of clause or the type of speech act. Everything depends on context, of course, but *do this*, without a *please* is likely to be considered a directive in terms of speech acts. *Directive* is a broad term, if we want a finer grained analysis, we might say that it is an order. When we add the word *please*, it is still a directive. But if we wish to give it a more finely-grained type of speech act label, we would probably now say that it is a request, or a polite request rather than an order. So, here, we do see that *please* arguably makes a significant difference to the type of speech act.

However, in terms of what grammatical type of clause a sentence is, the addition of *please* makes no difference at all. First of all, (21) lacks a tensed verb (and is not subjunctive), so it cannot be a declarative, closed interrogative, open interrogative, or exclamative main clause. In addition, it is a fully well-formed sentence even though it lacks an overt subject - and the addition of *please* does not change this.

21. Do this.
22. Do this, please.

We can add a first or third person subject, but not a first person one (without changing the meaning):

24. You do this, please.
25. Everybody do this, please.
26. *We do this, please. (ungrammatical)

We need the auxiliary *do* to make a negated version of the clause, and to make an emphatic one:

27. Don't do this, please.
28. *Do* do this, please.

And this still would be true if it was an imperative which use the verb *be*:

29. Don't be difficult, please.
30. Do be careful, please.

And lastly, if we include a subject and negate the clause, the word *don't* comes before and not after the subject, regardless of the word *please*:

31. Don't anybody do this, please.

We can see, then, that although the type of speech act is affected by the word *please*, it does not change the syntactic type of the clause involved.

Comment: Very thorough. I'll add (you can include it if you prefer) that declarative questions usually take question marks despite the declarative structure, and polite (or less polite; the 'please' isn't absolutely necessary) requests ("Would you just open the window, John.") don't mandate question marks.

Answer (score -1):

It is important to define the term "imperative" contextually - it does not **only** mean "command/order":

OED **imperative** (adj/ noun)

> **1.** *Grammar.* **Designating a verbal mood, construction, or form expressing a** command, **request**, warning, offer, or **entreaty**;
> of or **relating to this mood.**
>
> 1795 The Imperative Mode is used for commanding, exhorting,
> intreating, or permitting. *L. Murray, English Grammar 39*
>
> 1985 A better candidate than let for quasi-modal status, in informal
> English, is the first person imperative marker let's. *R. Quirk et
> al., Comprehensive Grammar of English Language 148*

1. "Please" makes absolutely no difference to the category of statement.
2. The Quirk quote is particularly relevant here as the first person imperative is also no more than a request/entreaty.